# Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.2.5

Tags: android, gradle

New into native android, getting a weird issue while building for first time on my formatted windows machine.
Ive developed the code on Mac, and it runs smoothly.

Error is  and hence it fails while building too[image]

```
Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.2.5
```

any idea on what can be the error?

my app gradle is

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unique.dailyreminder"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.2.6"

    def lottieVersion = "3.7.0"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$room_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Try add these `plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle.

> The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated. Instead, add
> dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need.

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-alpha02"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    // Annotation processor
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

Pre-AndroidX Versions (which is wrong for your project):

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

Comment: how does it work for my mac then? its the same build.gradle and no errors

Comment: ive tried with 1.1.1 and it worked, thanks for that, but can you help me understand why it didnt work and do you see any thing which is wrong in my build.gradle

Comment: @GauravRoy, you use `def room_version = "2.2.6"` and `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$room_version"`, but this library doesn't exist in 2.2.6 version, only 1.1.1 or less.

Comment: I thought you used AndroidX, so was wondered how could you mix AndroidX and Pre-AndroidX libraries.

Comment: okay, so umm, how to convert that to androidx?

Comment: @GauravRoy, please, see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle. Replace libraries with corresponding names (`implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")` and so on).

Comment: @GauravRoy, thank you! Current version is 2.3.1. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you go on Google's maven Repository and you look for the library in question you notice that the latest version of the library you are trying to use that's available is 1.1.1 while the one in your build.gradle is 2.2.6 so try changing it to 1.1.1 like so change "room_verson" to "1.1.1" like so:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unique.dailyreminder"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
            optimize.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    def lottieVersion = "3.7.0"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$room_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

}
```

link to library:
https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=lifecycle#android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1

Comment: wait, how does it run for my mac then? its the same build.gradle

Comment: woah thanks btw, how did you know its 1.1.1 and also are there any errors you can see

Comment: i checked on the repository that the library is from and as far as i can see i dont see any errors